# Force street address with Google Places Autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I know that I can restrict Google Places API to only return addressers using
the option `types: ['address']`. I was wondering if it is possible to force a user to give a street address including street number, that is "Drottninggatan 100" and not just "Drottninggatan"?

If I cannot force this behaviour, what would be a good way of validating that the user has selected something like "Drottninggatan 100" and not just "Drottninggatan"?

(btw I'm using the Javascript API and AngularJS)

Comment: Forcing a user to input a value a certain way sounds like textbook example of validation to me. Most logic place for you to do the form validation, would be in Angular.

Comment: What about using the terms array list count, make sure it has at least 5 items. Combining this to check that at least a number exists, but numeric and word (one) - not full proof but seemingly one of the validation best combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. you can use the javascript match function with regex to check the format of the input... The following example would check if the address contains at least a number.

```js
var resultBox = document.getElementById("ifValid");

function textboxChanged(){
    var address=document.getElementById("address").value;
    
    
    if (address.match(/[0-9]/i)==null){
        resultBox.style.color="red";
        resultBox.innerHTML="not valid";
    } else {
        resultBox.style.color="green";
        resultBox.innerHTML="valid";
    }

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="address" placeholder="enter an address" onkeyup="textboxChanged()">
    
<p id="ifValid" style="color: red;">not valid</p>
```

Comment: I thought about the same validation but unfortunately this will not be valid if a user had entered a zip-code. It would be a falsy true return. So sad google does not provide this option to us.

Comment: this solution has an issue. sometimes street numbers are not numbers

Answer (score -1):

Why not checking for number at the beginning of the address string?

```js
var resultBox = document.getElementById("ifValid");

function textboxChanged() {
  var address = document.getElementById("address").value;

  var parts = address.split(' ');
  if (parts.length > 1 && !isNaN(parts[0]) && parts[1].length > 0) {
    resultBox.style.color = "green";
    resultBox.innerHTML = "valid";
  } else {
    resultBox.style.color = "red";
    resultBox.innerHTML = "invalid";
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="address" placeholder="enter an address" onkeyup="textboxChanged()">
<p id="ifValid" style="color: red;">not valid</p>
```

[JS Bin demo: https://jsbin.com/vayanu](https://jsbin.com/vayanu)

Comment: Bad practice. A street number may be, for example, 5A. Google Places Autocomplete provides the place data in an object and there's the street number separated from the rest of the data.